# Why QObject::sender() returns null with QSignalMapper?

Tags: qt, qt5

I am using QSingalMapper for multiple QSlider and QCheckBox both are working fine.I want to check signal sources in slot.But **QObject::sender();** always returns **NULL**;

```
  void MainWindow::UpdateTempValues(int val)
  {
     QSlider *m_slider = qobject_cast<QSlider*>(QObject::sender());
      if(m_slider)
           ui->label_34->setText(QString::number(m_slider->value()));
  }
```

```
    QSignalMapper *checkBoxMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
    QList <QSlider *> SliderList = this->findChildren <QSlider *>();
    QList <QCheckBox *>CheckBoxList = this->findChildren<QCheckBox *>();

    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(UpdateTempValues(int)));
    connect(checkBoxMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(UpdateInOuConfigRegisters(int)));

    foreach(QSlider *w, SliderList) {
                   signalMapper->setMapping(w,SignalMaperID);
                   connect(w, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
                   SignalMaperID++;
            }
    SignalMaperID = 0;
    foreach(QCheckBox *c,CheckBoxList){
               checkBoxMapper->setMapping(c,SignalMaperID);
               connect(c, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), checkBoxMapper, SLOT(map()));
               SignalMaperID++;
    }
```

Comment: Who invokes UpdateTempValues? the mapped signal from QSignalMapper, and then who is the sender? it is the object that emits the signal that invokes the slot, in this case QSignalMapper, QSignalMapper can be converted to QSlider? No, does the above explain the problem?

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you so much, it's working now. i just replace ** connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget ***)), this, SLOT(UpdateTempValues(QWidget *)));** and **UpdateTempValues(QWidget *xSource){QSlider *m_slider = qobject_cast<QSlider*>(xSource);}

Comment: You do realize [`QSignalMapper`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html) is obsolete, right? There are much cleaner ways to accomplish things IMHO... eg. lambdas, or using dynamic properties on the sender objects to identify them in the signal handler (`QObject::setProperty()/property()`).